# cypress input field wont get cleared

Tags: reactjs, redux, cypress

I have a input field:

```
<input value="0">
```

which i can easily clear() and type("123") in cypress.
the value gets updated and everything is fine.

on the other side, a prefilled input field like below I cant update because cypress writes my value of .type("123") just at the beginning of the value.

```
<input value="1500000">
```

my method is the following:

```
   .find("input")
            .clear()
            .type(`${input}{enter}`)
```

changes on the fields fire redux actions, we use redux for our whole state handling. could that be a problem?

otherwise, do you know of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested using the HTML found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_value) and everything works fine (in the screenshot I wrote "Stefano" instead of the default value)

[image]

You hit the point when you cite React: this kind of state changes requires a bit more work to run as expected because React (and Vue etc.) obviously overwrites everything in the DOM.

You're facing a common issue where React re-renders the component as soon as an event is triggered... so you have to change the input value/defaultValue management in your React component, Google for it and you find a plethora of solutions about that

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an assertion to make Cypress 'wait' for the input to clear:

```js
.clear().should('have.value', '')
.type(...)
```

Comment: I tried this and it works sometimes and in some cases, it also fails saying it is not equal to an empty string(' ')